# Draw Place marker & path google map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a google maps route code.In this code this marker goes to the supplied Latitude & Longitude.

> What i need is : I have a another two points.those are pre-defined.( I need to draw that path with marker A & B for starting point & End point with path in same map.
>
> Start Lat & Long 2.852888, 101.651970
> End Lat & Long 2.941660, 101.594207

This code shows that

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
  <style type="text/css">
    html {
      height: 100%
    }
    
    body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0
    }
    
    #map {
      height: 90%;
      width: 90%
    }
  </style>

  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=geometry"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var line;

    var map;
    var pointDistances;

    function initialize() {
      var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(2.881766, 101.626877),
        zoom: 12,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };




      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

      // var myLatLng = {lat: 2.941660, lng: 101.594207}; //2.852888, 101.651970
      // 2.941660, 101.594207


      // var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      //    position: myLatLng,
      //    map: map,
      //    title: 'Hello World!'
      // });
      var lineCoordinates = [
        new google.maps.LatLng(2.86085, 101.6437),
        new google.maps.LatLng(2.87165, 101.6362),
        new google.maps.LatLng(2.880783, 101.6273),
        new google.maps.LatLng(2.891517, 101.6201),
        new google.maps.LatLng(2.8991, 101.6162),
        new google.maps.LatLng(2.915067, 101.6079)
      ];

      map.setCenter(lineCoordinates[0]);

      // point distances from beginning in %
      var sphericalLib = google.maps.geometry.spherical;

      pointDistances = [];
      var pointZero = lineCoordinates[0];
      var wholeDist = sphericalLib.computeDistanceBetween(
        pointZero,
        lineCoordinates[lineCoordinates.length - 1]);

      for (var i = 0; i < lineCoordinates.length; i++) {
        pointDistances[i] = 100 * sphericalLib.computeDistanceBetween(
          lineCoordinates[i], pointZero) / wholeDist;
        console.log('pointDistances[' + i + ']: ' + pointDistances[i]);
      }

      // define polyline
      var lineSymbol = {
        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
        scale: 6,
        strokeColor: '#393'
      };

      line = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: lineCoordinates,
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 2.0,
        strokeWeight: 5,
        icons: [{
          icon: lineSymbol,
          offset: '100%'
        }],
        map: map
      });

      animateCircle();
    }


    var id;

    function animateCircle() {
      var count = 0;
      var offset;
      var sentiel = -1;

      id = window.setInterval(function() {
        count = (count + 1) % 200;
        offset = count / 2;

        for (var i = pointDistances.length - 1; i > sentiel; i--) {
          if (offset > pointDistances[i]) {
            console.log('create marker');
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              icon: {
                url: "https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/markers2/measle_blue.png",
                size: new google.maps.Size(7, 7),
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(4, 4)
              },
              position: line.getPath().getAt(i),
              title: line.getPath().getAt(i).toUrlValue(6),
              map: map
            });

            sentiel++;
            break;
          }
        }

        // we have only one icon
        var icons = line.get('icons');
        icons[0].offset = (offset) + '%';
        line.set('icons', icons);

        if (line.get('icons')[0].offset == "99.5%") {
          icons[0].offset = '100%';
          line.set('icons', icons);
          window.clearInterval(id);
        }

      }, 20);
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  </script>


</head>

<body>
  <div id='map'></div>
</body>

</html>
```

ACTUALLY I need another path in this map like below image.(above mentioned Geo cordinates)

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what do you need. You have one path, are you want to create another one?

Comment: @MoshFeu Yes with markers

Comment: Why it's different from the path you already implements? What exactly the issue?

Comment: @MoshFeu This blue color path is already given path ( to the driver from his manager in my scenario )

Comment: Where do you want to place the markers?

Comment: @lavro for this locations Start Lat & Long 2.852888, 101.651970
End Lat & Long 2.941660, 101.594207

Comment: I get it that you want another path. I mean, why can't implement it as you implemented the first one. Why do you need us? (I mean, if you know to do something, you can do this again, easily, no?)

Comment: @MoshFeu picture i get it from internet.thatswhy

Comment: I just try to understand.. Do you mean that you want to place markers at the start and the end of the route in your code?

Comment: @MoshFeu My code is correct.In that code i need another path like in my picture with two place markers.( Finally my map has two paths.. Red color path with moving item and Blue color path with two place markers ) are you clear ?

Comment: I think.. What is the coords of the new path (the blue one)?

Comment: @MoshFeu Start Lat & Long 2.852888, 101.651970
End Lat & Long 2.941660, 101.594207

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, here is my approach.

See the `drawBlueLine` method.

```js
var line;

var map;
var pointDistances;

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(2.881766, 101.626877),
    zoom: 12,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

  var lineCoordinates = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(2.86085, 101.6437),
    new google.maps.LatLng(2.87165, 101.6362),
    new google.maps.LatLng(2.880783, 101.6273),
    new google.maps.LatLng(2.891517, 101.6201),
    new google.maps.LatLng(2.8991, 101.6162),
    new google.maps.LatLng(2.915067, 101.6079)
  ];

  map.setCenter(lineCoordinates[0]);

  // point distances from beginning in %
  var sphericalLib = google.maps.geometry.spherical;

  pointDistances = [];
  var pointZero = lineCoordinates[0];
  var wholeDist = sphericalLib.computeDistanceBetween(
    pointZero,
    lineCoordinates[lineCoordinates.length - 1]);

  for (var i = 0; i < lineCoordinates.length; i++) {
    pointDistances[i] = 100 * sphericalLib.computeDistanceBetween(
      lineCoordinates[i], pointZero) / wholeDist;
    console.log('pointDistances[' + i + ']: ' + pointDistances[i]);
  }

  // define polyline
  var lineSymbol = {
    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
    scale: 6,
    strokeColor: '#393'
  };

  line = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: lineCoordinates,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 2.0,
    strokeWeight: 5,
    icons: [{
      icon: lineSymbol,
      offset: '100%'
    }],
    map: map
  });

  animateCircle();
  
  drawBlueLine(map, lineSymbol);
}


var id;

function animateCircle() {
  var count = 0;
  var offset;
  var sentiel = -1;

  id = window.setInterval(function() {
    count = (count + 1) % 200;
    offset = count / 2;

    for (var i = pointDistances.length - 1; i > sentiel; i--) {
      if (offset > pointDistances[i]) {
        console.log('create marker');
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          icon: {
            url: "https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/markers2/measle_blue.png",
            size: new google.maps.Size(7, 7),
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(4, 4)
          },
          position: line.getPath().getAt(i),
          title: line.getPath().getAt(i).toUrlValue(6),
          map: map
        });

        sentiel++;
        break;
      }
    }

    // we have only one icon
    var icons = line.get('icons');
    icons[0].offset = (offset) + '%';
    line.set('icons', icons);

    if (line.get('icons')[0].offset == "99.5%") {
      icons[0].offset = '100%';
      line.set('icons', icons);
      window.clearInterval(id);
    }

  }, 20);
}

function drawBlueLine(map, lineSymbol) {
  console.log();
  var startBlue = new google.maps.LatLng(2.852888, 101.651970);
  var endBlue = new google.maps.LatLng(2.941660, 101.594207);

  var blueLine = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [startBlue, endBlue],
    strokeColor: '#0000ff',
    strokeOpacity: 2.0,
    strokeWeight: 5,
    icons: [{
      icon: lineSymbol,
      offset: '100%'
    }],
    map: map
  });
  
  new google.maps.Marker({
    position: startBlue,
    map: map
  });
  
  new google.maps.Marker({
    position: endBlue,
    map: map
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

#map {
  height: 90%;
  width: 90%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=geometry"></script>
<div id='map'></div>
```